# DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE sometimes returns NULL for the same input and passphrase

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, encryption

A strange issue that occurs sometimes.

The environment is Microsoft SQL Server Web (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard (10.0). **SQL Server version is 14.0.1000.169**

I have a table, TableA with a column ColEncrypted and primary key column PK. The data type of PK is int and it is auto incremented. The datatype of ColEncrypted is varbinary(500) and the column is nullable. This column is used to stored date value in encrypted format.  Before encrypting the date, it is first converted to nvarchar in format yyyyMMdd. So for e.g. April 1, 2020 becomes '20200401'. Thus the data to be encrypted is always 8 characters in length. This value is then encrypted using the T-SQL function EncryptByPassPhrase. So the encrypting is done as follows.

- First a row is inserted in the TableA without any value in ColEncrypted. So ColEncrypted is NULL at insert time
- An update statement is called to update the ColEncrypted column with the value to be encrypted as follows:

  UPDATE TableA SET ColEncrypted = ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(@passphrase,
   @date,1,CONVERT(VARBINARY,PK)) 
   WHERE PK = @Id
- @passphrase is a nvarchar(50) value of length 12
- @date is nvarchar(25) with date value in format yyyyMMdd. For e.g.
  April 1,    2020 is '20200401'
- PK is the primary key of the TableA and is an    identity column of
  data type int. It is used as authenticator. Thus    each row has a
  unique authenticator.

Decryption is done in a stored procedure as follows:

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR,DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(@passphrase,ColEncrypted,1,CONVERT(VARBINARY,PK))) FROM 
TableA WHERE PK = @Id
```

Now sometimes the decrypted value is NULL. Strangely the same value when encrypted again is decyrpted properly.

The one interesting thing I found is that the datalength of encrypted value for which the decrypted value is NULL is 67 whereas the datalength of encrypted value for which decryption occurs properly is 68, if this is something to consider.

**Edit 1: (In response to Andrew's comments)**

According to MS, VARBINARY when used in cast without specifying a size defaults to 30, which is sufficient enough. Look at the Remarks section in this article. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/binary-and-varbinary-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

So that can't be a issue otherwise it would have failed each time. As for sysname, if you look at the example provided here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/encryptbypassphrase-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15
, CreditCardId is used as authenticator by converting it to varbinary where a sysname datatype is expected. CreditCardId is a varchar datatype but nowhere I have found that int datatype cannot be used as long as I am converting it to varbinary.

Again as I mentioned this issue does not occur consistently. i.e. for the same input values for which the decryption fails, if I re-run the code for encryption, the decryption succeeds the next time. Therefore I suspect the issue is in the SQL Server engine. I have raised this question in SQL Product feedback but so far there is no response from them

Comment: Could it be an issue with the PK conversion? What if you specify a length to `VARBINARY` both when encrypting and decrypting? When you get NULL, it's because either the passphrase or the authenticator information is wrong. You may want to do some tests with a hardcoded int value instead of using the PK field, just to confirm this is what's causing your problem.
Another thing I noticed in the documentation: it says that the authenticator should be of type `sysname`, which is like a `nvarchar(128) NOT NULL`.

Comment: Still there, @devanalyst?

Comment: @Andrew, sorry for being late. I have responded to your comments in Edit 1 section in the post

Comment: Considering they *should* be the same, did you, just to be 100% sure, try using a constant authenticator, or using a different data type? It could be an esporadic bug related to some data types combination or internal casts. If you create a script to do this logic with an example of the input value which failed, and run it in loop thousands of times, does it ever fail? Or does it only fail when grabbing the value from a table?